# Android MediaCodec: How to determine the width and height of frames which are ready to be decoded

Tags: android, decode, android-mediacodec

Normally if we already have the width and height of frames through metadata we would define a mediaFormat object like this, to decode the frames:

```
 mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(
        MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_MPEG4,
        720, 1024
    )
```

And then:

```
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, Surface(textureView.surfaceTexture), null, 0)
```

But if we just have the encoded frames and no meta-data to know about the resolution, Is there any way to get the width/height?

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.
Every media container format includes metadata about the data stream.
Given only an encoded frame you are not expected to be able to use it:
Which codec was used to encode it? What is the frame size, pixel format, color space? All this information (and more) is required for decoding and playback.